# What exactly is the purpose of Meta?

Tags: discussion, meta

I'm fairly new to SE and wonder what exactly Meta is supposed to be used for?

Comment: Doesn't this question belong in Meta Meta?  (just kidding)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of Programmers.SE, the [main](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) site is to discuss *anything related to programming* (further defined in the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq)). Whereas the [meta site](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) exists to discuss *the main site*.

If you take a look at the [recent popular questions in Meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=month), you'll find:

- bug reports
- generic questions regarding to Programmers.SE
- suggestions to FAQ modifications
- discussions on which questions are on and off topic (for the main site)

All of which do not contain anything directly related to programming.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend reading the /faq

https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/faq

> This site is for meta discussion about [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). That is, things like:
>
> 1. Are questions about _____ on or off topic?
> 2. What should our FAQ contain?
> 3. How should we tag questions about _____?
> 4. What should our [elevator pitch be](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/)?
> 5. What should our site design look like?
> 6. Who should [the moderators be](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)?
> 7. How do we [promote our site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/)?
>
> See [The 7 Essential Meta Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) for more details.